# How to set the background colour of different legends in plotyy (Matlab)?

Tags: matlab, plot, colors

If I execute following code:

```
figure
t=0:.1:10;
dummy=plotyy(t,sin(t),t,2*cos(t));
    set(dummy(1),'ylim',[-1 1]);
    set(dummy(2),'ylim',2*[-1 1]);
    axes(dummy(1)); xlabel('xlabel'); ylabel('ylabel');
    axes(dummy(2)); ylabel('ylabel2');
    dummy(1).YTick=[-1:.5:1];
    dummy(2).YTick=[-2:1:2];
    legend(dummy(1),'Legend1','Location','NorthWest')
    legend(dummy(2),'Legend2','Location','NorthEast')
```

I obtain following figure:
[image]

It seems that the default colour of the right-hand legend is grey instead of white. Which command do I need to enter in order to make it white?

Comment: Good question - do you really want to know `why`, or is it rather that you want to have it white in both cases!? You could control the color by using `l1 = legend(...); set(l1,'color','white');`.

Comment: @tim - Thanks. In the end it is ok that I can make the legends white without knowing why they were not by default. I invite you to repeat your comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a good question, I can only assume that MATLAB try's to match some colors for readability or something like that. If you want to know it exactly, maybe MATLAB provides a legend.m-file within the program directory which you could open to have a look at the specific source.

In case you only want to know how to work around it to make both legends white, use this code:

```
l1 = legend(...);
l2 = legend(...);
set(l2, 'color' 'white');
```